# Pray barefoot or not?

Tags: tefilla, moshe-rabbeinu, parashas-shemos

At the burning bush, God told Moses:

> Remove your sandals from your feet, for the place on which you stand is holy ground. [Ex. 3:5].

Later, the kohanim served barefoot in the Temple.

But the Talmud says:

> It is disrespectful to uncover one’s feet in front of his Master. [Chagigah 13b]

The Rambam "sort of" confirms, throwing the ball to local custom:

> One should not stand in prayer ... barefoot where the local custom is not to stand in the presence of the great without shoes. [Mishneh Torah, Prayer and the Priestly Blessing 5:5]

Why did God's instruction to Moses not result in the halacha being to *always* pray barefoot?  Is this discussed anywhere?

Comment: Can you clarify why you're lumping together the place of the temple precluding shoes and how one dresses when praying?

Comment: Seems like in biblical days the expectation was to go barefoot before God.  Then it changed.  Why?

Comment: Can you prove that? The burning bush is called a holy place, which precludes shoes. So too the Temple. What does that have to do with prayer

Comment: Are you saying a synagogue is not a "holy place"?  Random quote:  A permanent study hall is more holy than a synagogue, and it is a mitzvah to pray in it more so than in a synagogue. [Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 90:18]

Comment: Another quote:  If they built a regular house and sanctified it afterwards to be a synagogue, its laws are like [that of] a synagogue; but it is not holy until they pray in it, even if they built it as a synagogue. [Shulchan Arukh, Orach Chayim 153:8]

Comment: Maurice Have you ever looked at Sefer Nefesh HaChaim and what it means to remove ones sandals/shoes?

Comment: @YaacovDeane -- No, but please enlighten me and tell me how it answers my question.

Comment: Like is explained there, this expression is referring to different levels of self-nullification (relating to preparation for a prophetic experience). You might find it of interest to compare what is asked of Yehoshua in that regard as compared to Moshe.

Comment: I'm not saying a synagogue isn't a holy place. All I see is two locations on earth which preclude shoes. Where do you see that all holy places, or as you said earlier 'before G-d', require a removal of shoes

Comment: Shemot 3:5 and Yehoshua 5:15.

Comment: @robev -- The way God phrased it implies you must be barefoot in *all* "holy places".

Comment: That's one way to understand it. I understand Mount Sinai as having special holiness. In any event your question really is why don't we take off our shoes in shul. A person praying by themselves according to what you're saying would need shoes. It's not about prayer it's about holy places.

Comment: Worth noting the Aruch Hashulchan - https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.91.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi worth noting the Pirkei DeRebbi Eliezer on the pasuk in Shemos who makes the link between Moshe removing his shoes and the future service in the Beis Hamikdash being done without shoes - https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_DeRabbi_Eliezer.40.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: it has everything to do with what is acceptable in the contemporary culture. in ancient times people did not wear shoes in front of kings, but nowadays we would never dream of removing our shoes in front of someone important

Comment: @ezra -- We are talking about prayer inside our synagogues.  At any rate halacha does not rest on "what is acceptable in the contemporary culture".

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi actually in some cases it does. the first thing that comes to mind is that for example a man usually cannot trim his body hair unless it is an acceptable practice by men in the local secular culture